# Possible to execute two or more than two commands at the same time?

Tags: shell

Is it possible to pass two command at the same time in a linux shell?
For example,
 Instead of writing commands in this way,

```
root# cd Python-2.6.6
Python-2.6.6# ./configure
```

I want something like this to execute whole command in one line;

```
root# cd Python-2.6.6 ./configure
```

That is, while being in root, i want to change the directory and configure python file..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an appropriate command separator.

```
cd Python-2.6.6 && ./configure
```

Comment: Thanks, I am running these commands from python script which will run on the client side to get python installed in remote server. If i run this code in linux, it worked, but when i execute it in from client side i receive error,
['configure: WARNING:\n', '\n', '  By default, distutils will build C++ extension modules with "g++".\n', '  If this is not intended, then set CXX on the configure command line.\n', '  \n']

Comment: So... do you not want to build C++ extension modules with g++ then?

Comment: Well I am quite new to linux. Did not understand your question. But this was the warning message that i got when i run the script. This did not create problem while I was running it from linux , but when i run it from client side (python code), after this message the program stops. How to ignore this message while passing commands?

Comment: You can give additional parameters to configure which will control how (with what options) python will be built. To see a list of these parameters, run `./configure --help` and then select the appropriate options for your target system.